# How can I align text both left and right in a C# WinForms button?

Tags: c#, button, text-justify

Sorry if I missed an existing post, but all the ones I see are for Android and CSS and stuff, not C#.

I am making a media manager and when I search I have a flow layout panel that populates with buttons that will launch movies matching the search.  What I want to do is have button text like this (assuming pipe | is the side of the button):

```
| Martian, The             [4K UHD] |
| Hard Rain                 [1080p] |
| Life of Pi                   [4K] |
```

I can justify in one direction, but not both.  Is it possible?  Thanks!

Comment: You can set the UseCompatibleTextRendering property to true, then use the TextAlign property.

Comment: TextAlign doesn't support Block alignment. With fixed fonts you can fake it.  - Or combine the Text with ownerdrawing the right aligned text : `using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Far, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center })
                e.Graphics.DrawString("sadasdasdasdasdas", Font, Brushes.DarkGoldenrod, button4.ClientRectangle, sf);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to create a custom button that inherits from `Button` and override its `OnPaint` event (building on TaW's comment).

```
 public class DuelTextFieldButton : Button
{
    public string LeftText { get; set; }
    public string RightText { get; set; }
    public Color RightTextColor { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);

        using (SolidBrush leftTextBrush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor))
        {
            using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat()
                    { Alignment = StringAlignment.Near, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center })
            {
                pevent.Graphics.DrawString(LeftText, this.Font, leftTextBrush, this.ClientRectangle, sf);
            }
        }

        using (SolidBrush rightTextBrush = new SolidBrush(RightTextColor))
        {
            using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat()
                    { Alignment = StringAlignment.Far, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center })
            {
                pevent.Graphics.DrawString(RightText, this.Font, rightTextBrush, this.ClientRectangle, sf);
            }
        }
            
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added using statements to brushes, as suggested by TaW's comment.

Comment: Do put the Brushes into a using clause, please. Also, for even better quality TextRenderer is recommended when painting controls..

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much, I love that I can even set the color of the different sides :)  

TaW, I modifed the code based on your comment such that it now looks like:
        using (SolidBrush leftTextBrush etc etc) {
          using (SolidBrush rightTextBrush etc etc) {
            using (StringFormat sf...  etc

Is that right?  Thanks!  Err it doesn't save CR.  I have them on their own lines actually.